# What should be unipotent de Rham homotopy group?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, algebraic-number-theory, fundamental-group

What exactly should unipotent $\pi_1^\text{dR}$ be conceptually? What formal properties should it satisfy? This seems to be answered by Chen's theorem,   which is stated in Corollary 3.269 of [Multiple zeta values: from numbers to motives](http://javier.fresan.perso.math.cnrs.fr/mzv.pdf), copied below. We let $M$ be a complex manifold.

> Corollary 3.269.  For every point $x \in M$, the iterated integral induces an isomorphism of Hopf algebras
>
> $$H^0(B^*(A^*)) \xrightarrow\sim \mathcal O(\pi_1(M, x)^\text{un}) \otimes \mathbb C.$$

Here

- $A^*$ is a complex quasiisomorphic to $\Omega^*(M)$, the differential forms on a manifold.
- $B(A^*)$ is the reduced bar complex. So $B(A^*)$ is a dg Hopf algebra.
- $\pi_1(M,x)^\text{un}$ is the pro unipotent group scheme associated to $\pi_1(M,x)$.

Questions:

1. Why should one expect this to be an isomorphism? To me, the left hand side is the $0$th cohomology of $B\Omega^*(M)$ which should be $C^*(\Omega_x(M))$ where $\Omega_x(M)$ is the pointed loop space of $M$. So why should the $H^0$ of the complex be regarded as the unipotend de Rham $\pi_1$? (If I were to match the right hand side.)
2. Where do I say the unipotence from the left hand side?
3. Often $H_*(\Omega_xM)$ is related to the  Lie algebra $\pi_1(M)$ under Whitehead bracket, is there any relation here?

Comment: Since text in images can't easily be searched, it is better to type out short passages like the one in your image.  I have edited to do so.